# How can I process vector difference between 1 group layer and 1 polygon layer?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, loop, differences

I have one layer group called 'left_buffer', containing 40 buffered polygon layers (name: 1,2,3,...,39,40). I want to use difference vector tool between 'left_buffer' and 'bldg' layer, but I'm getting error message.

```
for i in range(40):
    processing.run("qgis:difference", {'INPUT': 
    'left_buffer'[i+1], 'OVERLAY':'small_bldg', 
    'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/sky/Desktop/1/' + str(i+1) 
    + '.shp'})
```

error message: Could not load source layer for INPUT: e not found

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: What is 'left_buffer'[i+1] in the input supposed to be? At the moment it's finding 'e' because it's the 2nd (index 1) letter in 'left_buffer', which it can't find; On the first iteration i = 0 so i + 1 is 1, if you run in a python window you will find 'left_buffer'[1] is 'e'.

Comment: yes. I realized that 'left_buffer'[i+1] literally refer to 'l','e','f','t',...'e','r'. Do you know how to address layers in group in pyqgis? QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("left_buffer")[0] wouldn't work since it's not a single layer but a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Identification of my overlay layer
small_bldg = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("small_bldg")[0]

# iteration on the 40 layers
for layer in range(1,40):

    # Identification of my input layer
    left_buffer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(str(layer))[0]

    # Run your processing
    processing.run("qgis:difference", {'INPUT': left_buffer, 'OVERLAY':'small_bldg', 
    'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/test/'+ str(layer)+'.shp'})
```

Comment: I've attached a picture of what my layers look like in original post. ```small_bldg = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("small_bldg")[0]``` works because it's not included in group. But ```left_buffer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("left_buffer")[0]``` doesn't work. How can I address 1-40 layers in 'left_buffer' group?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that you created a group with 40 layers. I thought you had 40 polygons in the same layer. Therefore, my old request is no longer valid, I have updated it.

Comment: it works! I changed```mapLayersByName(layer)``` into ```mapLayersByName(str(layer))``` and it works perfectly :) thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for your answer, I added the str.